# Convert file bat for mac

Tags: macos, batch-file, terminal

On Windows I use this file bat that allows me to start the artisan application without having to do everything manually every time

```
cd c:\xampp\htdocs\gamelite-lv
php artisan serve
```

I tried to replicate the script for Mac, but I can't use it:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ..
cd ..
cd Applications
cd mamp
cd htdocs/lv/
php artisan serve
```

moreover, with the batch for mac, is it possible to create a system of choices like?

```
@ECHO OFF
:StartLoop
CLS
ECHO 1.Start Laravel
ECHO 2.Update Composer
ECHO 3.Install Composer
ECHO 4.Show Router
ECHO 5.Run SASS
ECHO.
CHOICE /C 12345 /M "Select choice:
```

Comment: This site and its membership do not perform a free conversion or coding service. We expect you to perform your own research and write your own code. If your code does not function as written and intended, then this site and membership may be able to assist you in fixing it. Please take the [tour] and read [ask], before following the above advice. If you still have issues once your code is finished, you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53981376/edit), to include a [mcve] of your code, complete with before and after results and any errors output. Thank you.

Comment: I read everything, @LegoLiam; you used some code, which you stated that you could not use, _i.e. no explanation, results, errors or indication as to its functionality_, and a batch file choice menu, with no attempt to replicate in a MacOS terminal. So I redirect you to my previous comment.

Comment: if you are running a bash script none of those in the last set will work. the bash shell may contain any command that works on the terminal, so "Start" is maybe "open". and "Run" is accomplished by typing the name of what you want to run.  If you list what specific commands you want to execute someone may be able to help you.

Comment: Please delete comments containing information which belongs in your question proper, and edit your question as previously asked. [I've also done a StackExchange search for you](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1705), regarding the menu, _despite your inability to show us that you've made any attempt at researching this yourself!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that:

```
PS3='Choise: '
options=("Start Laravel" "Update Composer")
select opt in "${options[@]}"
do
    case $opt in
        "Start Laravel")
            cd /applications/mamp/htdocs/lv
            php artisan serve
            ;;
        "Update Composer")
            cd /applications/mamp/htdocs/lv
            php composer.phar update
            ;;
        *) echo "$REPLY invalid choice";;
    esac
done
```

In order to start the file with a double click I renamed the .command file, and I set the permissions:

```
chmod ugo+x file
```